# userNotificationCenter willPresentNotification Overriding application didRecieveNotifiction in Dev but not Prod

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate, nsnotificationcenter

Very odd problem I've been stuck at for a while.

Im working on a code base that has a notification center which handles remote notifications, but the AppDelegate also handles remote notifications.

// Notification Center handler

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    log.debug("@AppDelegate: willPresentNotification: \(notification)")
}
```

// App Delegate Notification Handler

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    log.debug("@AppDelegate: didReceiveRemoteNotification: \(notification)"
}
```

The strange behaviour I am having is that push notifications seem to work on production (when we build for the app store). However, when I send push notifications in Dev, the `userNotificationCenter willPresentNotification` handler fires but the `application didReceiveRemoteNotification` does NOT fire.

I can't test why it seems to work in production (since you can't attach the debugger) so I don't quite understand why that seems to be happening.

Do you know why `userNotificationCenter willPresentNotification` may (or may not) intercept the `application didReceiveRemoteNotification` in production vs dev (or any other reason it might intercept the notification handler)? When I remove the `userNotificationCenter` code the standard `didReceiveRemoteNotification` fires in dev.

Any insight greatly appreciated thank you.